# Persisting mysql database with docker

Tags: python, mysql, docker, docker-compose, mysql-python

I am trying to containerise a Python script and MySQL database using Docker. The python script interacts with a program running on the host machine using a TCP connection, so I've set up a "host" network for the Docker containers to allow this. The python script is currently speaking to the program on the host machine fine (TCP comms are as expected). The python script is also communicating with the MySQL database running in the other container fine (no errors from pymysql). When I use the Docker Desktop CLI interface I can see the timestamps on the files in `/var/lib/mysql/donuts/*.ibd` on the database container updating as the python code pushes info into the tables.

However, my problem is that when I bring both containers down using `docker compose down` and then bring them up again using `docker compose up` the information in the database is not persisting. Actually, if I enter the database container using the CLI using `mysql -u donuts` and then try to manually inspect the tables while the containers are running, both tables are completely empty. I've been going in circles trying to find out why I cannot see the data in the tables even though I see the files in `/var/lib/mysql/donuts/*.ibd` updating at the same instance the Python container is inserting rows. The data is being stored somewhere while the containers are running, at least temporarily, as the python container is reading from one of the tables and using that information while the containers are alive.

Below are my `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` files and the entire project can be found [here](https://github.com/jmccormac01/donuts_voyager). The python code that interacts with the database is [here](https://github.com/jmccormac01/donuts_voyager/blob/master/voyager_db.py), but I think the issue must be with the Docker setup, rather than the Python code.

Any advice on making the database persistent would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.25
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    secrets:
      - mysql_root
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/mysql_root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: donuts
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql-init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mysql-init.sql
    network_mode: "host"

  voyager_donuts:
    container_name: voyager_donuts
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: voyager_donuts
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
      - c:/Users/user/Documents/Voyager/DonutsCalibration:/voyager_calibration
      - c:/Users/user/Documents/Voyager/DonutsLog:/voyager_log
      - c:/Users/user/Documents/Voyager/DonutsData:/voyager_data
      - c:/Users/user/Documents/Voyager/DonutsReference:/voyager_reference

volumes:
  mysql-data:

secrets:
  mysql_root:
    file: ./secrets/mysql_root
```

```
# get a basic python image
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

# set up Tini to hand zombie processes etc
ENV TINI_VERSION="v0.19.0"
ADD https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini /tini
RUN chmod +x /tini

# keep setup tools up to date
RUN pip install -U \
    pip \
    setuptools \
    wheel

# set a working directory
WORKDIR /donuts

# make a new user
RUN useradd -m -r donuts && \
    chown donuts /donuts

# install requirements first to help with caching
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy from current dir to workdir
COPY . .

# stop things running as root
USER donuts

# add entry points
ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--"]

# start the code once the container is running
CMD python voyager_donuts.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And of course as soon as I post this I figure out the answer. My database connection context manager was missing the `commit()` line. Le sigh, I've spent much longer than I care to admit on figuring this out...

```py
@contextmanager
def db_cursor(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='donuts',
              password='', db='donuts'):
    """
    Grab a database cursor
    """
    with pymysql.connect(host=host, \
                         port=port, \
                         user=user, \
                         password=password, \
                         db=db) as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            yield cur
```

should have been:

```py
@contextmanager
def db_cursor(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='donuts',
              password='', db='donuts'):
    """
    Grab a database cursor
    """
    with pymysql.connect(host=host, \
                         port=port, \
                         user=user, \
                         password=password, \
                         db=db) as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            yield cur
        conn.commit()
```